# How to remove some HTML tags inside a <div>?

Tags: jquery, dom

I am displaying some formated text in HTML within a `<div>`.
Unfortunately, the formated text contains full html page where I only need the paragraph with the text inside.

Here is the original source :

```html
<td class="tdInfo"><a href="#" onclick="displayInfo(61);">Probl&egrave;me r&eacute;seau informatique</a><div id="memo61" class="info"><html><head>

</head>
<body>
<p>Nous rencontrons en ce moment un problème sur le réseau informatique</p>

<p>Pour plus d'informations :&nbsp;<a href="http://www.eureka-solutions.fr/" target="_blank">info</a></p>

</body></html></div></td>
```

And I want to strip the HTML to obtain this :

```html
<td class="tdInfo"><a href="#" onclick="displayInfo(61);">Probl&egrave;me r&eacute;seau informatique</a><div id="memo61" class="info">
<p>Nous rencontrons en ce moment un problème sur le réseau informatique</p>

<p>Pour plus d'informations :&nbsp;<a href="http://www.eureka-solutions.fr/" target="_blank">info</a></p>
</div></td>
```

I have tried unwrap() function but it removes the `<div>` and I want to keep the `<div>` and only strips HTML within the `<div>` element :

```js
function displayInfo(key) {
   var id = 'memo'+key;
   $("#"+id).children("p").unwrap();
   $("#"+id).slideToggle();
  }
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The HTML in your first example is invalid

Comment: The problem is that the invalid HTML is going to be ignored when you try to add it to the DOM. You can't remove it because it's never added in the first place.

Comment: I know it's invalid, but I can't do anything about it. I receive the formated text from a SQL query and unfortunatetly, the application gives me that. The problem is, even if this invalid HTML is ignored, it brokes my display and I have huge empty spaces before and after my text. In my mind, clearing the DOM was the only way.